# Creating a table with a check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Database Manager, and I am creating some tables, and have walked into a problem;

I am trying to create a table, which has two foreign keys;
EmpID
MemberID

Both of these CAN be null, but realistically, either would be null and the other wouldn't at a given time when entering data, (XOR logic) for example;

if EmpID is not null, then MemberID would be (when entering data).

I have a boolean attribute (represented as a BIT) called IsEmp
And I'm trying to create a check to see whether;

if EmpID is NULL, then isEmp = 0, else isEmp = 1, so when I enter data, I dont have to worry about this, and it would do it automatically. Below is the query I entered which I thought would work, but gave me an error;

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerDetails (
DetailID    int IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EmpID       int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmpID),
MemberID    int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProntoClub(MemberID),
IsEmp       BIT NOT NULL CHECK (EmpID > 0),
FLineAdd    VarChar(20) NOT NULL,
SLineAdd    VarChar(20) NOT NULL,
Town        VarChar(20) NOT NULL,
PostCode    VarChar(8) NOT NULL,
ContactNo   Char(11),
EMail       VarChar(35),
DoB         DATE NOT NULL
```

)

I did some snooping around google to find an answer, but the problem I came across was people's examples were for example;

```
IsEmp       BIT NOT NULL CHECK (IsEMP > 0),
```

Which confused me as how I could implement a check for one attribute, that checks another if this makes sense?

I was wondering if this is actually possible? Or if I am approaching it in the wrong way.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsEmp should be a computed column

```
IsEmp as case when EmpID > 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

A check constraint spanning columns needs to be defined at the table level.

```
create table CustomerDetails (
    -- ... cols ...
    constraint ck_name check (
      EmpID + MemberID is null
      and coalesce(EmpID, MemberID) is not null
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

IsEmp       BIT NOT NULL CHECK ((IsEMP > 0 AND EmpID IS NOT NULL) OR (IsEMP = 0 AND EmpID IS NULL))